# ngrok : File C:\Users\....\AppData\Roaming\npm\ngrok.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system

Tags: node.js, ngrok

ngrok : File C:\Users\dines\AppData\Roaming\npm\ngrok.ps1 cannot be loaded because running
scripts is disabled on this system. For more information, see about_Execution_Policies at
https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
At line:1 char:1

- ngrok http 3000
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess
  ```

When I run ngrok http 3000 command

Comment: Have you tried reading the link provided with the error message?